# IIS changing website physical location does nothing

Tags: iis, blazor-server-side

I'm updating a .net app, and in IIS Manager running on an Azure Windows Server VM.

I changed the physical path of my site to a new folder (renaming the old folder).

However, after restarting the page / app pool / IIS / server, the old site is still being served.

Even stopping the application doesn't bring it down.  What do I need to do to make the new version of the site "take?"

Comment: Where did you launch the browser and what was the URL used? When a connection is set up, there are too many caches along the way, so you should identify all involved first before moving directly to the server itself. Try to always open a private tab of your web browser for testing, which at least removes the impact of browser side cache.

Comment: The browser is on my home computer, and the URL points to a live Windows VM.  If I stop the app pool in IIS, the site goes down, which makes me (a n00b admittedly) believe that the caching is taking place on the server.  I tried incog mode in Chrome, as well as launching the site in Edge.

Comment: People will need access to your server to identify what exactly happened. Several things can go wrong, so not easy to conclude without seeing your IIS settings and site contents.

Comment: Yeah, I get that.  IIS is a real wilderness for me, and who knows HOW I might screw it up.  Today, I was able to replicate the bad behavior on my dev machine-- the site worked fine in debug on the dev machine, but Release build showed the same broken behavior as the published site.

Comment: Did you solve the problem after trying to clear the cache?

Comment: "Did you try turning it off and on again."  Absolutely, I cleared everything that was clearable, restarted the site, server, entire VM several times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who thought about this question.

I had a few problems, actually:

1. CSS Isolation broke the Release version but not the Debug version on the local machine (I'm not sure why).  This is probably something that happened in not updating from .net 5 to .net 6 properly.  I've removed CSS isolation for now, and made a clean upgrade to .net 7, and the site is running great.
2. I was running my Blazor site as an app in my old WebForms site, but also had the app listed as a separate site, and they were pointed at different folders.
3. For SOME reason, the security certificates for the site got reset, leading to a total failure to connect (this took me a LONG time to find, because I never manually deselected the certificates, and it just timed out instead of throwing a no-certificate warning).

Finding the problem was really painful, tbh.  It was only after inspecting the live site / release and debug versions carefully and noticing differences in the [idlabel] markups that I realized the problem.